# Correctly Specifying an annotation processor with Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, annotations

I'm trying to specify a local project as an annotation processor for an annotation (which I also declared in that project).

IN the base projects dependencies I've tried a bunch of things, including defining it like this:

```
implementation project(':ToolsProject')
annotationProcessor project(':ToolsProject.AutoLog:AutoLogProcessor')
```

I can't seem to figure out the notation to directly point the annotationProcessor command to the package within the local project